# res.send() after res.redirect() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send a variable to the page after I have redirected to another page. I have very basic knowledge in Node.js and can't seem to figure out a way to do that. Here's my code.

```
app.get('/search' , function (req, res) {
var postcode = req.query.search;
var ward = my_search.getWardNum(postcode,(ward) => {
    res.redirect('/:ward'+ ward);
   });
});


app.get('/ws/:postcode' , function (req, res) {
    var postcode = req.params.postcode.replace("+","");
    console.log(pc);
    my_search.postcodeLookUp(pc,(ward) => {
        var area = my_search.lookupWard(ward);
        res.send(area);
    });
});
```

So in the first `app.get()`, I get the postcode and redirect to another page. 
However, I still need that postcode with second `app.get()`.
I understand that nature of node.js is async. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: what does `:ward` parameter suppose to represent in your `res.redirect('/:ward') + ward`

Comment: the value of the ward that i get from getWardNum() method

Comment: So maybe you might want to do `res.redirect(`/${ward}`)` instead I'm not really sure what the concatenating the ward to the url does for you.

Comment: this didnt work when i tried it? so I want the url be like locallhost/'wardNum'

Answer (score 1):

When you "redirect", you're not just changing the URL the user sees, you're sending a HTTP response with a status code indicating that the client should try to access another page instead.

You can't send data after you redirect because the full response has already been sent! You should consider *why* you're redirecting and if it is really necessary. You could also redirect to a route containing the URL parameter that you want to be present:

```
res.redirect('/ward/' + ward + '/' + postcode);

...

app.get('/ward/:wardID/:postcode', (req, res, next) => {
   // route code here...
});
```

Note that you'll probably want a prettier format than that, but that is one way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks that helped. But the problem is I kinda need to merge these two methods together. /ws/:postcode is basically a dummy endpoint which accesses the postcode and then does some operations on that. Both of these methods will eventually takes the user to the map.html page.  which is the /:ward path.

Comment: What do you mean "merge these two methods together"?

Comment: like If rather than having 2 separate end points, just have one and some how manage to redirect and send through the same endpoint. I'm sorry if this might sound stupid. I have literally limited knowledge with async languages and still trying to get my head around it